# How do I drive this display?

Tags: microcontroller, driver, display

I would like to know how to drive [this little e-Ink display](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/1-54-inch-smart-watch-e_60229407980.html?spm=a2700.8443308.0.0.8VAiBT). The company supplies a [demo kit](https://wholesaler.alibaba.com/product-detail/For-small-size-electronic-paper-display_60644571433.html?spm=a2700.details.pronpeci14.1.36008291c0wUcn) and a sort of "adaptor circuit" (basically a breakout board with a few capacitors, which allows one to use the same demo kit with several displays).

The question is, if I want to incorporate such a display into my own design, how do I go about doing it? Because I don't see an MCU anywhere on the display. So do I have to buy any driver, or is it there any MCU on the chip I don't see?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you think that little black strip on the left side was?

Comment: No idea, but I certainly did not suspect this was an MCU. Is it?

Comment: It's a driver. You will still need whatever MCU you want to use to direct the display, but you use SPI instead of driving the display directly.

Comment: So sorry for a stupid question then! Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.